# Как правильно составить обработку условий

Tags: php, sql

Есть вот такой ajax обработчик, при каждом обращение переменная `$num` уменьшается на 12:

- `Get: 32/12 rows`
- `Get: 20/12 rows`
- `Get: 8/12 rows`
- `Get: 0/12 rows`

Как видно из последней строки записи которые будут выведены это `Get: 8/12 rows` если отнять `8-12=-4` то записи больше не будут выводиться.
Но у нас еще осталось 8 записей как их вывести?
Как правильно сделать обработку?
Должно быть так `Get: 0/8 rows`

```
$mesgs = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT a.id, a.aut, a.mesg, a.timestamp, b.name, b.email FROM txt_mesgs a LEFT JOIN users b ON b.id = a.aut WHERE a.tid = '".$id."' ORDER BY a.timestamp ASC LIMIT 0, ".$num."");
```

А так же если в таблице к примеру 15 записей, то нужно вывести остаток (3) `Get: 0/3 rows`

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['num']) && isset($_POST['tid']) && is_numeric($_POST['num']) && is_numeric($_POST['tid'])) {
    $num = $db->EscapeString($_POST['num']);
    $id = $db->EscapeString($_POST['tid']);

if ($num > 0) {
    $mesgs = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT a.id, a.aut, a.mesg, a.timestamp, b.name, b.email FROM txt_mesgs a LEFT JOIN users b ON b.id = a.aut WHERE a.tid = '".$id."' ORDER BY a.timestamp ASC LIMIT ".$num.", 12");
    foreach($mesgs as $mesg){
?>
<div id="<?=$mesg['id']?>" class="ticket_mmesg">
    <img class="ticket_mavatar" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/<?=md5(strtolower(trim($mesg['email'])))?>?s=45" alt="<?=ucfirst($mesg['name'])?>" />
    <div class="ticket_mtime-name"><div class="ticket_musername"><?=ucfirst($mesg['name'])?></div><div class="ticket_mtime"><?=date('H:i', $mesg['timestamp'])?></div></div>
    <div class="ticket_mdelete"></div>
    <div class="ticket_mtext"><?=$mesg['mesg']?></div>
</div>  

<?php
    }
} else {
    $db->Close();
    echo 0;
}
}else{
    echo 'Error';
}
?>
```

-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var check_messages = setInterval(function () {
            var scrollPosition = $('#ticket_mscroll').scrollTop();
            if (scrollPosition == 0) {
                load_tickets();
            }
        }, 1000);

    var num = 32; //Всего у нас 56 сообщений, 56-24 =32 (На экране 12 сообщений уже выведено)

    function load_tickets() {
        var tid = 1;
        $.ajax({
            url : "get.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : {
                "num" : num,
                "tid" : tid,
            },
            cache : false,
            success : function (las_messages) {
                if (las_messages == 0) { // смотрим ответ от сервера и выполняем соответствующее действие
                    //$(".ticket_mhead").append("<div> Error </div>");
                    clearInterval(check_messages);
                } else {
                    $("#doload").prepend(las_messages+' '+num+'/12');
                        num = num - 12;
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Если честно, я вообще не понял, как первая часть вашего вопроса связана с тем, что написано после первого кода с SQL-запросом, ибо там нет ничего ни про `ajax`, ни про уменьшение `num`, а только выборка и рендер 12 записей из какой то таблицы, начиная с `$num`. Так что лучше вам включить вашу `ajax` часть в вопрос.

Comment: Приветствую, добавил Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Разверните `order by` в вашем sql-запросе:

```
$mesgs = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT ..  ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC ...");
```

Т.е. `DESC` вместо `ASC`

Так вам будет нужно брать записи в более стандартном варианте. В вашем примере на 15 записей последняя будет:

```
$mesgs = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT ..  ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC 
             LIMIT $num 12");  //$num=12
```

- `LIMIT 0 12` -> 0 - 12
- `LIMIT 12 12` -> 12 - 15

База данных сама выведет 3 последних записи. Никаких дополнительных действий не потребуется.